# Using .hdf5 files only once they are finished writing

Tags: python, h5py

I am trying to use `.hdf5` files once they are done writing (in my case, trying to emit them). But the problem is that I don't have a way to 1) test if they are finished writing and 2) then send them. The code that I have been trying to work with is follows:

```
    while True:
        event = self._q.get()
        while True:
            try:
                file = h5py.File(event.src_path, "r")
                file.close()
                self.new_file.emit(event.src_path, os.path.basename(event.src_path))
                break
            except OSError:
                if retry_count < max_retry_count:
                    retry_count += 1
                    print(f"h5 file <{event.src_path}> is locked, retrying {retry_count}/{max_retry_count}")
                    time.sleep(retry_interval_seconds)
                else:
                    print(f"h5 file <{event.src_path}> reached max retry count, skipping")

            except Exception as err:
                print(f"Got unexpected Error <{type(err).__name__}> while opening <{event.src_path}> ")
                traceback.print_exc()
```

Obviously this is problematic with the `break`. But without the break, the `try` stays in the loop and emits the same file over and over again. This code tests if they are done writing perfectly but the ability to send them and continue to take in new files does not work. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say it "does not work", do you get an error message? Does the script unexpectedly terminate? Have you tried the `.emit()` code with test files of similar size and nature and does it work when you try that?

Comment: When I keep the `break` there, it can only send out one file (i.e. the first file). But when trying to then load a new `.hdf5`, it doesn't work. This makes sense since the `break` leaves the while loop. When I remove the `break`, there is an infinite loop. Essentially how I ended up doing it doesn't make sense with the `break`

Comment: Two issues:
1. If you have trouble with emitting a second file, you have to show us the surrounding code that includes this second file. We can't tell what's wrong in code we cannot see.
2. Your lock-retry code may be insufficient. What operating system are you using? Who is writing the file, a second process, a second thread, a process on a different system via network file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by the following code:

```
    while True:
        event = self._q.get()
        max_retry_count = 350  # for test purposes now but want to set an upper bound on verifying a file is finished.
        retry_interval_seconds = .01  # every hundreth it will try the file to see if it finished writing
        retry_count = 0
        if event.event_type == "created" and event.src_path.lower().endswith(".hdf5"):
            while True:
                try:
                    file = h5py.File(event.src_path, "r")
                    file.close()
                except OSError:
                    if retry_count < max_retry_count:
                        retry_count += 1
                        print(f"h5 file <{event.src_path}> is locked, retrying {retry_count}/{max_retry_count}")
                        time.sleep(retry_interval_seconds)
                    else:
                        print(f"h5 file <{event.src_path}> reached max retry count, skipping")
                        break  # <--- looks useful here
                except Exception as err:
                    print(f"Got unexpected Error <{type(err).__name__}> while opening <{event.src_path}> ")
                    traceback.print_exc()
                else:
                    self.new_file.emit(event.src_path, os.path.basename(event.src_path))
                    break
```